# easy_install : skip looking through package index on pypi

Tags: python, easy-install, pypi

Is there a way to get `easy_install` to skip looking through the package index @ Pypi?

I have setup myself my egg repo on Amazon S3 and I would like to speed up the process of installing from this repo but `easy_install` keeps insisting on looking at Pypi first.

(and Pypi access is currently broken from home and amazon :(

Comment: Are you using `-i/--index-url`? In the code I see `self.index_url = self.index_url or "http://pypi.python.org/simple"`, so it seems it should work.

Comment: @jcollado: thanks for this! Just gave me an idea to speed things up :)